# Why will my unit tests only run on a my apps, not my entire project?

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-2.7

I've just started writing my first unit tests for a django project, but have come across an issue when attempting to run all the projects tests.

If I run the tests for a specific module/app it works fine:

```
./manage.py test my_project.api --settings=my_project.settings.test
```

But when I attempt to run all tests in the project:

```
./manage.py test my_project --settings=my_project.settings.test
```

I get an error for every tests.py that's found:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: my_project.api.tests.tests (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: my_project.api.tests.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
        module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name
        __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named my_project.api.tests.tests
```

I am using virtualenvwrapper with the following,

python 2.7.1

django 1.6.1

Anyone know why this might be happening?

**EDIT**

This is an abbreviated view of my project structure:

```
my_project_root
    |
    |
    |--- my_project
    |        |
    |        |--- api
    |        |     |
    |        |      ---- tests
    |        |             |
    |        |              --- tests.py
    |        |--- core
    |        |     |
    |        |       ---- tests
    |        |              |
    |        |               --- tests.py
    |         --- settings
    |                |
    |                 ---- test.py
    |
    |
     --- manage.py
```

Reading the django docs,

"Test discovery is based on the unittest module's built-in test discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named “test*.py” under the current working directory."

Which is /my_project_root/

Comment: Are you ok with switching to [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? - it will help to overcome your test discovery problems.

Comment: Looks like you have a `PYTHONPATH` (or generic path) setting problem. Presumably, `manage.py` lives in the `my_project` directory. Try adding one directory up to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @alecxe i did take a look at nose, but doesn't django 1.6 include django-discover-runner? Are they a solution to the same problem?

Comment: @Evert i see what you mean, if i just use ./manage.py api -settings=my_project.settings.test then that works running each modules individual tests. Am i right in thinking that i use virtualenvwrappers add2virtualenv to add to PYTHONPATH? If so, i've tried that and it hasn't worked?

Comment: That's very odd. Given the project structure you showed, I wouldn't expect that you'd need to do anything unusual with PYTHONPATH or add2virtualenv; in fact I would avoid doing so, as most likely you'll end up with overlapping import paths then.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` within every directory under `my_project`?

Comment: Carl, thanks for mentioning that, it got me thinking. I'm hosting my app on heroku and had to add an __init__py at in /my_project_root/ so that the Procfile can find wsgi.py in /my_project/. I've just deleted it and now all the tests run fine. It's a hollow victory as i'm not sure why it's happening and obviously need it there for heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was (partially) solved within the comments, it was a combination of an environment configuration error and how test discovery works.

Put simply, `__init__.py` should not be present within `my_project_root`.

To make heroku be able to discover `wsgi.py`, the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable should be adjusted to include `my_project_root`.

Additionally, you can specify

```
heroku config:set WSGI_PATH=path/to/my/file/wsgi.py
```